# screen adjusting ability feature in android

Tags: android, touchscreen, android-layout

I have an application which is designed for a fixed screen size.But when i install the application on a device with different screen size ,i am not able to view the complete application.
Is it possible to allow layout adjustments based on variable screen sizes?  ... like setting width with some % of screen size which is decided when application installation is done
For eg: 60% of screen size or 60% of relative layout

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is actually very easy in Android: just dont declare a screen size, and let the OS handle it. The only time your screen is a fixed size is when you declare it as a fixed size. If you're having trouble, go back to the first tutorials from google. In their layouts, they never explicitly declare a screen size.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I have not declared any screen size but while running my application with emulators of different sizes like 4 inches or 7 inches or any other value, the result varies.

Comment: That's strange. I guess i would need to see your source to tell for sure.

Comment: Sorry for this but I am able to do it with different size of emulators but not actual device of different screen sizes and resolution

Answer (score 1):

You can find out about the size of the screen by using `getWindowManager()`.

So, for example, to find out what 60% of your screen width is you could do this in your `onCreate()` method:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm); 
int sixtyPercentScreenWidth = (int) Math.round(dm.widthPixels * 0.6);
```